# Put span on top of div

Tags: html, css

I built some social buttons with counters. And I want the counter data to show on top of my buttons. Somehow they are always inside the buttons.

1. Is it possible to put the number of shares on top of the button, how?
2. Each social button has text inside, even though I put `float: left` and `text-align: left`,
    the text still shows in the center, why?

Please see my fiddle... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/1jp2nhuu/)

My HTML:

```
<a class="post-share facebook entShare" target="entsharewindow" href="#">
<div class="social-buttons-text">Facebook Like</div><span>0</span>
</a> 
<a class="post-share facebook entShare" target="entsharewindow" href="#">
<div class="social-buttons-text">Facebook Share</div><span>0</span>
</a> 
<a class="post-share twitter entShare" target="entsharewindow" href="#">
<div class="social-buttons-text">Twitter</div><span>0</span>
</a>
```

My CSS:

```
 a.post-share {
    display: block;
    width: 74px;
    height: 34px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: #3e599a url(sidebar-share.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    width: 110px;
    text-indent: 50px;
    font: 15px/46px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a.post-share:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a.post-share span {
    width: 22px;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: block;
    float:right;
    background-color:#080563;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-style:bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: 10px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    text-indent: 0;
}

a.post-share.facebook {
background-color: #3B5998;
background-image: url('/images/social-icons/facebook-32.png');
margin-right: 10px;
}

a.post-share.facebook {
background-color: #3B5998;
background-image: url('/images/social-icons/facebook-32.png');
margin-right: 10px;
}


a.post-share.googleplus {
background-color: #D14836;
background-image: url('/images/social-icons/googleplus-32.png');
margin-right: 10px;
}

.social-buttons-text {
    font-size:4px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/1jp2nhuu/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you can set `a` tag `position:relative` and the `span` inside it `position:absolute` and give `top` and `left` to align it in `position`

```css
a.post-share {
  display: block;
  width: 74px;
  height: 34px;
  float: left;
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: #3e599a url(sidebar-share.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 110px;
  font: 15px/46px"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
}
a.post-share:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a.post-share span {
  width: 22px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 3px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #080563;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font: 10px"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0;
}
a.post-share.facebook {
  background-color: #3B5998;
  background-image: url('/images/social-icons/facebook-32.png');
  margin-right: 10px;
}
a.post-share.facebook {
  background-color: #3B5998;
  background-image: url('/images/social-icons/facebook-32.png');
  margin-right: 10px;
}
a.post-share.googleplus {
  background-color: #D14836;
  background-image: url('/images/social-icons/googleplus-32.png');
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.social-buttons-text {
  font-size: 4px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<a class="post-share facebook entShare" target="entsharewindow" href="#">
  <div class="social-buttons-text">Facebook Like</div><span>0</span>
</a>
<a class="post-share facebook entShare" target="entsharewindow" href="#">
  <div class="social-buttons-text">Facebook Share</div><span>0</span>
</a>
<a class="post-share twitter entShare" target="entsharewindow" href="#">
  <div class="social-buttons-text">Twitter</div><span>0</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! But why does my text inside button still show in center, even though I put float:left and text-align:left???

Comment: Ah, sorry, I saw it already, its because of text-indent:50px; - my mistake! Thanks.